# Mice imputing NAs left

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to impute a dataset that has a lot of missing data.
I tried different variations in PredM and mice.
I am giving you a pretty big junk of my data, that is still randomly selected (in rows). If I go any smaller, the code won't show the same issues.

```
dput(data)
structure(list(ID = c(40L, 189L, 176L, 110L, 91L, 51L, 77L, 119L, 
68L, 185L, 236L, 116L, 182L, 145L, 201L, 62L, 144L, 221L, 48L, 
51L, 174L, 184L, 121L, 227L, 17L, 145L, 66L, 224L, 77L, 85L, 
202L, 192L, 188L, 33L, 192L, 37L, 173L, 38L, 67L, 82L, 157L, 
233L, 180L, 231L, 216L, 85L, 4L, 71L, 208L, 2L, 102L, 55L, 19L, 
206L, 13L, 77L, 110L, 136L, 212L, 157L, 112L, 58L, 225L, 213L, 
144L, 129L, 71L, 7L, 160L, 15L, 34L, 21L, 31L, 133L, 141L, 8L, 
97L, 221L, 23L, 194L, 211L, 193L, 211L, 29L, 205L, 146L, 84L, 
110L, 10L, 46L, 9L, 36L, 68L, 157L, 214L, 155L, 149L, 129L, 3L, 
204L, 128L, 193L, 113L, 222L, 94L, 228L, 220L, 151L, 34L, 217L, 
160L, 35L, 212L, 145L, 36L, 127L, 145L, 198L, 168L, 189L, 32L, 
55L, 82L, 67L, 111L, 17L, 22L, 91L, 226L, 40L, 3L, 46L, 163L, 
41L, 89L, 94L, 66L, 132L, 184L, 18L, 74L, 6L, 183L, 75L, 168L, 
32L, 13L, 22L, 8L, 90L, 235L, 72L, 48L, 10L, 170L, 52L, 49L, 
37L, 23L, 62L, 205L, 161L, 75L, 19L, 180L, 127L, 205L, 128L, 
161L, 9L, 97L, 155L, 101L, 29L, 117L, 36L, 79L, 148L, 9L, 5L, 
36L, 234L, 169L, 59L, 90L, 34L, 114L, 118L, 137L, 229L, 122L, 
47L, 183L, 175L, 173L, 184L, 157L, 216L, 69L, 53L, 30L, 50L, 
64L, 136L, 89L, 44L, 171L, 117L, 164L, 92L, 1L, 162L, 22L, 39L, 
117L, 132L, 177L), ab = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 
2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 
2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("m", "w"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(3.48, 3.99, 3.29, NA, 5.98, 3.64, 4.58, NA, 4.59, 
    2.35, 5.98, 2.31, 1.45, 4.71, 2.21, 3.39, 5.32, 4.33, 4.47, 
    3.64, 3.75, NA, 3.87, 0.28, 4.61, 4.71, 3.59, 4.02, 4.58, 
    3.06, 3.8, 3.99, 3.8, 3.29, 3.99, 3.29, 3.75, 3.48, 4.59, 
    3.75, 1.81, 3.3, 1.37, 3.56, 3.8, 3.06, 3.75, 2.55, 4.71, 
    5.62, 3.56, 5.98, 3.53, 3.75, 5.11, 4.58, NA, 3.73, 2.05, 
    1.81, 3.25, 5.98, 3.62, 2.05, 5.32, NA, 2.55, 3.75, 1.45, 
    4.44, 4.46, NA, 4.07, 1.45, 1.64, 4.61, NA, 4.33, 3.35, 3.08, 
    4.08, 5.38, 4.08, 4.75, 3.87, 3.87, 3.35, NA, 2.67, 3.64, 
    3.11, 4.47, 4.59, 1.81, 3.8, 5.98, 4.1, NA, 3.48, 3.87, NA, 
    5.38, 0.49, 4.08, 4.61, 0.3, 3.8, NA, 4.46, 4.05, 1.45, 3.73, 
    2.05, 4.71, 4.47, 4.31, 4.71, 4.7, 3.75, 3.99, 3.21, 5.98, 
    3.75, 4.59, 3.56, 4.61, 4.61, 5.98, 3.84, 3.48, 3.48, 3.64, 
    2.26, 3.62, 4.81, 4.61, 3.59, 4.71, NA, 4.58, 3.06, 3.39, 
    2.43, 2.79, 3.75, 3.21, 5.11, 4.61, 4.61, 3.73, 3.75, 5.3, 
    4.47, 2.67, 4.71, 3.75, 2.7, 3.29, 3.35, 3.39, 3.87, 5.11, 
    2.79, 3.53, 1.37, 4.31, 3.87, NA, 5.11, 3.11, NA, 5.98, 3.29, 
    4.75, 4.02, 4.47, 3.25, 2.81, 3.11, 3.1, 4.47, 3.8, 2.05, 
    2.73, 3.73, 4.46, 5.03, 3.56, 3.3, 4.75, 4.31, NA, 2.43, 
    3.39, 3.75, NA, 1.81, 3.8, 3.53, 3.08, NA, 2.98, 2.52, 3.73, 
    4.81, 3.48, 3.29, 4.02, 3.37, 3.29, 4.61, 2.9, 4.61, 3.54, 
    4.02, 4.71, 3.64), x2 = c(4.92, 11.75, 10, 12, 9, NA, NA, 
    7.75, NA, 17.42, 19.08, NA, 9, 12.17, 9.42, NA, 8.5, 8.17, 
    6.92, NA, 17, 13, 12.75, NA, NA, 12.17, NA, 12.92, NA, NA, 
    17.25, 14.17, 19.33, 11, 14.17, 13, 16, NA, NA, NA, 14.17, 
    NA, NA, NA, 12.42, NA, 15, NA, 12, 14.25, 14, 18, NA, 12.58, 
    NA, NA, 12, 8.92, NA, 14.17, 16, 10.58, 16, NA, 8.5, 7.83, 
    NA, NA, 12, NA, 16.83, 10.42, 9, 10.5, 12.67, 15, 6, 8.17, 
    NA, 5.58, NA, 15.67, NA, NA, 16.08, 14.92, NA, 12, 16, 13.42, 
    12.08, NA, NA, 14.17, NA, 17.25, 10.83, 7.83, NA, 11.75, 
    8.5, 15.67, 10, NA, NA, NA, 10.83, 11.33, 16.83, 16.17, 12, 
    10.83, NA, 12.17, NA, NA, 12.17, 9.58, NA, 11.75, 14, 18, 
    NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, 9, 7.92, 4.92, NA, 13.42, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 13, 13, NA, NA, 18.33, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, 15, 
    NA, NA, NA, 6.92, 16, NA, NA, 13.58, 13, NA, NA, 16.08, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.08, 8.5, NA, 12.08, 6, 17.25, 10, NA, 
    5, NA, NA, 11.08, 12.08, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.83, 17, 
    9, 11.67, NA, 15, 9, NA, NA, 16, 13, 14.17, 12.42, NA, 7.83, 
    10, 14.75, NA, 8.92, NA, 16, 8, 5, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, 12, 
    5, 13, NA), x3 = c(3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, 
    NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 3, NA, 
    5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 3, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 
    NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, NA, 4, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 
    3, NA, 3, 5, NA, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 3, NA, 3, 4, NA, 
    NA, 4, NA, 2, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, 
    3, NA, 5, 5, 4, NA, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, 1, 
    NA, 5, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 3, NA, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, 4, NA, 5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, 
    4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), x4 = c(60, 
    52, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 59, NA, NA, 73, 67, 56, NA, 
    65, 60, 54, NA, 74, NA, 66, NA, NA, 67, NA, NA, NA, NA, 67, 
    53, NA, NA, 53, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 55, NA, NA, NA, 76, NA, 
    NA, NA, 70, NA, 65, NA, NA, 54, NA, NA, NA, 62, NA, 55, 75, 
    65, 72, NA, 65, 81, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61, NA, 65, NA, 64, 65, 
    82, 60, NA, 73, NA, NA, NA, NA, 66, 70, NA, NA, 67, 77, 71, 
    NA, NA, 55, NA, 76, 63, 81, NA, 52, 62, NA, 71, NA, NA, NA, 
    59, 52, 61, 66, NA, 74, NA, 67, NA, NA, 67, 59, NA, 52, 70, 
    NA, NA, NA, 59, NA, NA, NA, 60, 60, NA, 77, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 53, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 70, NA, NA, 65, NA, NA, 
    NA, 54, 67, NA, NA, 31, NA, NA, NA, 66, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    66, 62, NA, 71, 82, 76, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 57, 71, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 61, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69, 62, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    55, 76, NA, NA, NA, 52, NA, 62, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 64, NA, 53, NA), S1.T = c(5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 4, 4, 
    2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 
    6, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 
    4, 4, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
    6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
    3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 
    6, 5, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3), 
    S2.T = c(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    6, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 
    2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 
    5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 
    3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 
    3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 
    4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 6, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 
    5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 6, 
    4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4), S3.T = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    6, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 
    2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 
    4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 
    1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 5, 2, 3, 5, 
    5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 6, 
    4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
    1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 
    3, 2, 3), S4.T = c(3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
    4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 
    2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
    2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
    4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 
    1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 
    3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3), S5.T = c(2, 1, 
    1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
    3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
    3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), S6.T = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
    1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 
    1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 
    3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 
    2, NA, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 4, 
    2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 
    1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2), S7.T = c(5, 
    4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 
    2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
    2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 
    3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 
    4, 2, 4, 2, 4, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 
    1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, NA, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
    5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 
    3, 3, NA, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 
    4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, 1, NA, 3, 3, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, NA, 3, 5), S8.T = c(4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 
    3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
    4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
    5, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 
    4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, NA, 1, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 
    4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
    3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), S9.T = c(2, 
    1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, NA, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
    1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
    1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 
    4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), S10.T = c(6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
    2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 
    2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
    2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 
    5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 
    NA, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 
    3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 1, NA, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 
    3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 
    4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5), S11.T = c(6, 
    1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 
    1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
    5, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 
    3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 
    4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 6, 3, 5, 
    1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 
    1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
    5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
    5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4), S12.T = c(5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 
    3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 
    4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, NA, 3, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
    3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, NA, 4, 
    3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, NA, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 3, 2, NA, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1), S13.T = c(3, 
    1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
    3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5, 2, 
    2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 
    2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 1, NA, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 1, NA, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 
    5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, NA, 2, 4, 2, 5, 
    1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1), S1.N = c(6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 
    6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, NA, 6, 7, 4, 7, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, NA, 6, NA, 5, 7, 
    7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 
    7, 6, 7, NA, 7, 7, 6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 
    6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, NA, NA, 7, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
    7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, NA, 7, 
    7, 7, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 
    6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6), 
    S2.N = c(6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 5, 5, 
    5, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, NA, 5, 6, NA, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, NA, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 1, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, 
    NA, 7, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
    6, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 4, 4, NA, 6, NA, NA, 
    6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 6, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 
    7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 
    6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, NA, 7, 7, 7, 3, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, NA, 7, 
    6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6), S3.N = c(6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, NA, NA, 6, 
    5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 7, NA, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, 6, 
    5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 
    6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, NA, 6, 6, 
    6, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 
    6, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 6, NA, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 7, 7, 6, NA, 
    6, NA, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, NA, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 7, 6, 6), S4.N = c(5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, NA, 
    NA, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    5, NA, 5, 6, NA, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, NA, 5, 6, 6, 5, 
    7, 7, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, NA, 5, 7, 5, 
    6, NA, 7, 5, 6, 6, NA, 6, NA, 7, 6, 5, 6, 5, 1, 5, 5, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 7, NA, 
    5, 4, 4, 5, 5, NA, NA, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, NA, 5, 6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, NA, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 5, NA, 6, 5, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, NA, 7, 
    5, 7, 4, NA, 5, 7, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 7, 6, 4, 6, NA, 7, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, NA, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5
    ), S5.N = c(5, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 
    5, 5, NA, 6, 5, 6, NA, NA, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, NA, 
    4, 6, NA, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, NA, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
    NA, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 7, 7, 7, NA, NA, 7, 6, 5, 
    NA, 7, 5, 6, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, 6, 5, 6, NA, 1, NA, 4, 6, 
    6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 1, 7, NA, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 5, NA, 7, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, 4, 6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 
    5, NA, 6, 5, 7, 6, 3, NA, 7, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, NA, 5, 
    6, 7, 4, NA, 5, 7, 5, 4, NA, 6, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 
    6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 
    6, 5), S6.N = c(5, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, NA, NA, 
    6, 6, 5, NA, 6, 5, 6, NA, NA, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 
    NA, 4, 6, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, NA, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 
    7, 5, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 7, NA, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, NA, 7, 4, 5, 
    NA, 7, 6, 7, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, 6, 4, 6, NA, 1, NA, 4, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 7, 5, 7, NA, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 7, NA, 
    4, 4, 4, NA, 6, NA, NA, 6, NA, 6, 7, 5, 6, NA, 6, NA, 7, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, NA, 4, 5, 6, NA, 6, 
    6, 5, NA, 5, 6, 7, 6, 4, NA, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 
    5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, NA, 
    5, 5, 7, 3, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, NA, 6, 4, 6, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, 
    7, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, NA, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 
    6, 5), S7.N = c(6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 
    6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7, NA, NA, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 4, 7, 6, 
    6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, NA, 7, 
    6, 7, 6, NA, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, 7, 6, 
    7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 
    6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 6, 
    6, 1, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
    6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 
    7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, NA, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
    6, NA, 7, NA, 7, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6), S8.N = c(6, 
    NA, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, NA, 6, NA, 6, 5, 
    6, NA, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 4, NA, 5, 6, NA, 7, 6, 
    6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, NA, 7, 6, 6, NA, 7, 6, 7, 6, NA, 
    6, NA, 7, 6, NA, 6, NA, 1, NA, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 
    6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, NA, NA, 7, 4, 5, 6, 6, NA, 
    NA, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 7, NA, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 3, 6, 
    1, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 
    3, NA, 6, 6, 4, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, NA, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 
    NA, 6, NA, 7, NA, 6, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 6, 6), S9.N = c(5, NA, 
    NA, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 
    NA, NA, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 7, 5, 
    6, 5, 6, NA, 6, NA, 4, 6, 5, 5, 7, 7, NA, 6, 5, 1, 6, 6, 
    7, NA, NA, 6, 7, 7, 7, NA, 6, 7, 5, 6, NA, 7, 6, 6, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, 7, 6, 4, 6, NA, 1, NA, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 7, 
    6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 7, 5, 5, 7, 1, 6, NA, 4, 4, 4, NA, 6, NA, 
    NA, 6, NA, 6, 7, 5, 6, NA, 7, NA, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 
    1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, NA, 4, 6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 6, NA, 6, 7, 6, 
    6, 4, NA, NA, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 
    5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, NA, 4, 7, 7, 7, NA, 5, 5, 7, 3, 6, 5, 
    NA, 6, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 
    7, 6, NA, NA, 6, NA, 7, NA, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 5), S10.N = c(7, 
    NA, NA, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 7, 
    7, NA, 6, 6, 4, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 6, 6, 
    7, 6, 7, 7, NA, 6, NA, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 
    7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 
    5, 7, 6, 4, 7, NA, 1, NA, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 
    5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 7, 1, 7, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, 6, NA, NA, 7, 
    6, 6, 7, 5, 6, NA, 6, NA, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 1, 7, 7, 
    7, 6, 7, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 
    6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 
    6, 5, 7, 6, NA, 6, 7, 7, 6, NA, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 5, 4, 5, 5, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, NA, 5, 
    6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6), S11.N = c(7, NA, 7, 7, 
    6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 7, 7, NA, 6, 
    6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 
    6, NA, 6, NA, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 
    6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 7, 7, 6, NA, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 5, 7, 6, 
    4, 7, NA, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6, 
    7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, NA, 3, 4, 6, NA, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    6, 6, NA, 7, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 6, 1, 7, 6, 7, 6, 
    6, NA, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
    7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 
    7, NA, 6, 7, 7, 6, NA, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 4, 
    5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, NA, 6, NA, 7, 5, 
    NA, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6), S12.N = c(6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 
    7, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6, 7, 6, NA, 6, 6, 4, 5, 
    6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, NA, 6, NA, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    NA, 4, 7, 7, 7, NA, 7, 6, 7, 6, NA, 6, 5, 7, 6, 3, 6, 5, 
    6, 5, 6, 6, 6, NA, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 
    7, 6, NA, 6, 6, 4, 7, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 
    6, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
    6, NA, 5, 6, 7, 6, NA, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 6, 6), S13.N = c(5, NA, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, NA, 
    NA, 4, 5, 6, NA, 6, 7, 6, NA, NA, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 7, NA, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, NA, 4, 7, 5, 
    6, 5, 7, NA, 6, 5, 1, NA, 6, 6, NA, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, NA, NA, 
    7, 6, 7, NA, 7, 6, 7, 6, NA, NA, 5, 7, 6, 3, 6, NA, 1, NA, 
    5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, NA, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 1, 
    NA, NA, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, NA, NA, 6, 5, 4, 7, 5, 4, NA, 7, NA, 
    7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, NA, 6, 6, 6, NA, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, NA, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 
    3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, NA, 5, NA, 7, 6, 
    NA, 6, 5, 7, 4, NA, 5, 6, 6, 4, NA, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    NA, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 
    7, NA, 6, 5), x5 = c(9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 10, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 1, 
    10, 7, 8, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 9, 5, 9, 7, 6, 7, 9, 9, 8, 
    8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 9, 9, 8, 6, 9, 10, 8, 6, 10, 
    8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 10, 6, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, NA, 
    10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 9, 5, 9, 8, 7, NA, 8, 8, 8, 10, 9, 
    9, 8, 9, 9, 10, 1, 10, 8, 10, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 9, 10, 8, 10, 
    7, 8, 5, 7, 8, 10, 6, 10, 8, 6, 7, 10, 8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 
    8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 9, 9, 9, 
    8, 10, 7, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 5, 10, 10, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 9, 
    7, 6, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 10, 7, 1, 9, 9, 9, 10, 9, 10, 
    9, 10, 1, 10, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 
    8, 9, 10, 6, 9, NA, 9, 9, 8, 10, 8, 10, 8, 9, 7, 9, 9, 8, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -217L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the basic code. I already tried different variations for the mice and quickpred function.

```
ip <- mice(data, maxit = 0)

meth1 <- ip$method
meth1["ab"] <- ""
meth1["gender"] <- ""

predM <- ip$predictorMatrix
predM <- quickpred(data = data, exclude = c("ID"))

ip1 <- mice(data = data, maxit = 5, predictorMatrix = predM, method = meth1, print = FALSE)
```

Comment: I need to add: For me, the mice argument doesn't show any warnings or errors. Plus, $loggedEvents gives NULL

Comment: Thanks for your imputation report, what are you actually asking? I tried your code and didn't notice any issues.

Comment: There are still NAs in the imputed variables in my code.. I would like there not to be. Specifically, x1,x2,x3,x4 are of interest.

Comment: I see. Do you actually auto generate the predictor matrix or just for the example here? Looks like in `predM` x1-4 predict each other which might be the reason that the attempt fails, because they have missings.

Comment: Ive tried not using quickpred and playing around with the quickpred arguments (minpuc, etc.). I either get the same results like the code above or even more problems with really high loggedEvents numbers. I'll try setting them so they do not predict each other, but the problem persists with other variables probably. Why doesn't mice impute all variables in this case, if there are no loggedEvents?

Comment: Update: It still does the exact same thing, even when x1-x4 are not supposed to predict each other.

Comment: The problem is, that in your predictors are missings which `mice` won't accept. Did you check if the left NAs in x1-4 correspond to missings in your predictors? Your code works using complete predictors `data1 <- data[complete.cases(data[!names(data) %in% c("ID", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")]), ]`, loosing a whole bunch of observations, though.

Comment: yes, I want to keep as many cases as possible, even at the expense of bias or other problems for now. Is there a way to tell mice to still impute, even when the predictors have missing themselves? could I for example tell mice that for the NAs it produces, its supposed to run it again or to impute with mean substitution or something?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to use a parametric imputation method (as MICE is one) when the parameters are actually not available. Furthermore you already have the right feeling that mean substitution is bad. However you could try a non-parametric method, I suggest a look into [missForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missForest/index.html) which is based on RandomForest and has good reviews (See [paper](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12232)).